# array.map is mutating my original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to update a field in an object in my array.

My object (simplified) looks something like this:

```
{
  "readableStructure": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "Name": "Name 1",
      "Description": "Adding, updating or removing users",
      "IconName": "fas fa-users-cog"
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "Name": "Name 2",
      "Description": "Views overview",
      "IconName": "fas fa-street-view"
    },
    {
      "ID": "3",
      "Name": "Name 3",
      "Description": "Improvements to apps",
      "IconName": "fas fa-broadcast-tower"
    },
    {
      "ID": "4",
      "Name": "Name 4",
      "Description": "Managing badges",
      "IconName": "fas fa-id-badge"
    },
    {
      "ID": "5",
      "Name": "Name 5",
      "Description": "Art",
      "IconName": "fas fa-hand-holding-heart"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
prepareRepositories(this.props.primarySearchRepositories);
```

I can have several similar repos and I loop through them. And for each item in the array `readableStructure` I am trying to add a property called `QSString` using the following code.

```
prepareRepositories(repositories) {

    const repos = repositories.map((repo, index) => {

        const searchableColumns = ['Name', 'Description'];
        const newRepo = [];
        newRepo[0] = {};
        newRepo[0].readableStructure = [];

        newRepo[0].readableStructure = repo[0].readableStructure.map((item) => {
            item.QSString = this.getSearchableString(item, searchableColumns) || 'blaha';
            return item;
        });

        return newRepo;
    });

    return repos;
}

getSearchableString = (base, searchableColumns) => {
    let searchables = [];

    Object.keys(base).forEach((key) => {
        if ((searchableColumns.indexOf(key) > -1) && (base[key] !== null) && (typeof base[key] !== 'object')) {
            searchables.push(base[key]);
        }
    });

    const searchableString = searchables.join(' ');
    return searchableString;
}
```

However, when I do this the original object is modified and the `QSString` property get set to the same thing for every repo.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: `item.QSString = this.getSearchableString ... ` -- this statement causes the issue. You're modifying the object in-place. What did you expect otherwise?

Comment: I am using react, hence calling the function `getSearchableString` with `this`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does not change the original array, i.e. creates a new Array. However, any object in the Array continues to hold the **same reference**, hence, any change in object even inside map function will update the object in original array.

You need to **create a copy for the object**.

```
item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

using this wont mutate the original object

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(your_object))
```